# WSO2: How to use config registry in Kubernete Enviorment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

We are using WSO2 in VM and used below code into mediation to save data inside registry

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
                importPackage(Packages.org.apache.synapse.config);
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-kid",false);
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-kid", mc.getProperty("keycloakkey-kid"));
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-x5c",false);
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-x5c", mc.getProperty("keycloakkey-x5c"));
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-timestamp",false);
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-timestamp", mc.getProperty("current-system-time"));
                ]]>
            </script>
```

But now same code i deployed in Docker and Kubenete environment and this is not able to save the data

How to use the registry in the case of Kubernete environment ?

What i tried

in deployment.yaml i added volume mount

```
 volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /keycloak/keycloakkey-kid
              name: keycloak
      volumes:
        - name: keycloak
```

and changed the js code as well

```
 <script language="js"><![CDATA[
                importPackage(Packages.org.apache.synapse.config);
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-kid",false);
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-kid", mc.getProperty("keycloakkey-kid"));
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-x5c",false);
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-x5c", mc.getProperty("keycloakkey-x5c"));
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-timestamp",false);
                mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-timestamp", mc.getProperty("current-system-time"));
                ]]>
            </script>
```

But still failing with error

```
2021-06-21 16:15:42,576] ERROR {MicroIntegratorRegistry} - Couldn't create resource: keycloakkey-kid
[2021-06-21 16:15:42,577] ERROR {MicroIntegratorRegistry} - Error when adding a new resource org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Couldn't create resource: keycloakkey-kid
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.handleException(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:655)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.createFile(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:830)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.addResource(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:813)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.newResource(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:562)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190._c_script_0(<Unknown Source>:3)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190.exec(<Unknown Source>)
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:395)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:290)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:258)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SwitchCase.mediate(SwitchCase.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:134)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:239)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:244)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:809)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:309)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[2021-06-21 16:15:42,581] ERROR {ScriptMediator} - {api:Orders} The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error when adding a new resource (<Unknown Source>#3) in <Unknown Source> at line number 3
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:395)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:290)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:258)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SwitchCase.mediate(SwitchCase.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:134)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:239)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:244)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:809)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:309)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error when adding a new resource (<Unknown Source>#3)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190._c_script_0(<Unknown Source>:3)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190.exec(<Unknown Source>)
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error when adding a new resource
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.handleException(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:650)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.newResource(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:564)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Couldn't create resource: keycloakkey-kid
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.handleException(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:655)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.createFile(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:830)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.addResource(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:813)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.newResource(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:562)
        ... 41 more
```

Comment: May you are not able to resolve the registry FQDN from the K8s. Make sure that the  resolv.conf is configured properly

Comment: Do i have to make a volume mount for this ?

Comment: Can you share the complete error trace that you are getting? And the version of MI that you are using in your environment?

Comment: @Athiththan I edited the question section, `ARG MICROESB_VERSION=4.0.0`

Comment: @Athiththan Any update about this?

Comment: I don't have much clue about this. It seems to be a permission issue where the MI was trying to create the resource and failing in the K8s environment. Can you check whether the Volume mounts are placed correctly and not having any issues there?

Comment: @Athiththan this is how i added Volume Mount added in my helm3 ...deployment.yaml
` volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /_system/config
              name: keycloak
      volumes:
        - name: keycloak`

Answer (score 1):

The above error happens when you run the **newResource** method in **MicroIntegratorRegistry** class more than once with the same resource path. You should be able to reproduce this error in a VM environment as well if you try out this same mediation flow for the second time. The reason is that **newResource** method in MicroIntegratorRegistry throws this error if the file already exists at the target location.

As a solution, you may use **newNonEmptyResource** method [1] in MicroIntegratorRegistry as follows to fulfill your requirement.

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
    importPackage(Packages.org.apache.synapse.config);
    mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newNonEmptyResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-kid", false, null, mc.getProperty("keycloakkey-kid"), null);
    mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newNonEmptyResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-x5c", false, null, mc.getProperty("keycloakkey-x5c"), null);
    mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newNonEmptyResource("/keycloak/keycloakkey-timestamp", false, null, mc.getProperty("current-system-time"), null);
    ]]>
</script>
```

The method signature would be like below.

```
public void newNonEmptyResource(String path, boolean isDirectory, String mediaType, String content,
                                  String propertyName);
```

Also, I was able to successfully mount the registry in the Kubernetes environment using the following configuration in pod definition file.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ...
    ....
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/wso2carbon/wso2mi-4.0.0/registry"
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /registry
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

or else with Docker, with below configuration in docker-compose.yml file ->

```
volumes:
      - ./registry:/home/wso2carbon/wso2mi-4.0.0/registry
```

**Note:** Make sure you give the absolute path to the MI-4.0.0 registry folder as the mount path (in my case it was "*/home/wso2carbon/wso2mi-4.0.0/registry*" inside the MI-4.0.0 docker container)

Also, I had to change the ownership of my mount path (/registry) as below to start the container successfully inside the pod.

```
user: wso2carbon
user id: 802
user group: wso2
user group id: 802
```

Command:

```
groupadd --system -g 802 wso2 \
&& useradd --system --home /home/wso2carbon -g 802 -u 802 wso2carbon
```

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/26d25fbe2f2535de2861b80525646ff28035f2f0/components/mediation/registry/org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry/src/main/java/org/wso2/micro/integrator/registry/MicroIntegratorRegistry.java#L573

Comment: Thanks I found the Solution and will update it. But as per your Solution `newNonEmptyResource` will not throw exception if code executed second time , the value will be updated with new value or it hold previous value only?

Comment: It will not throw an exception. But, the file content will be replaced with the new value passed through the method.